# how can i compare values in two unsorted int arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to find the same values (if there is) in both int arrays.
I think it would work with Binary Search but i don't know exacly how to do it.
e.g:

```
    g1[95 78 99 95 35 65 95]
    g2[67 100 95 76 95 99 60]

    the function returns 2 (for 95 and 99).
```

Comment: Looks like homework/interview question. Any requirements about speed/memory consumption/LINQ usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int compare(int g1[], int g2[])
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < g1.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < g2.length; j++)
        {
          if(g1[i] == g2[j])
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This code compare each array element of g1 with all of the second(g2), if he find a element equal increments the counter. The code is a little big, but I think it's easier for you to understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Enumerable.Intersect`:

```
int[] duplicates = g1.Intersect(g2).ToArray();
```

If you just want to know the number of duplicates:

```
int duplicates = g1.Intersect(g2).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `Intersect`

```
        var g1 = new[] { 95, 78, 99, 95, 35, 65, 95 };
        var g2 = new[] { 67, 100, 95, 76, 95, 99, 60 };
        var result = g1.Intersect(g2).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Var duplicates = g1.Intersect(g2).Count();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            int[] g1 = { 95, 78, 99, 95, 35, 65, 95 };
            int[] g2 = { 67, 100, 95, 76, 95, 99, 60 };

            int[] results = g1.Where(x => g2.Contains(x)).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested for each should do:

```
void a(int[] g1, int[] g2)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var x in g1)
    {
        foreach (var y in g2)
        {
            if (y == x) counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intersect 
var r= g1.Intersect(g2) and use foreach loop to get value from r.